# simple dom php 404 error

Tags: php, web-crawler

eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?php

include './simple_html_dom.php';

//Este link existe
$teste = new simple_html_dom("http://www.btolinux.com.br/");
echo $teste->original_size."<br>";
if($teste->original_size !== 0){
    $teste->find("html");
}

//Aqui estou forçando um erro 404.
$teste = new simple_html_dom("http://www.btolinux.com.br/error/");
echo $teste->original_size."<br>";
if($teste->original_size !== 0){
    $teste->find("html");
}

//A partir de agora todo objeto que eu criar vai estar com erro
$teste = new simple_html_dom("http://www.btolinux.com.br/");
echo $teste->original_size."<br>";
if($teste->original_size !== 0){
    $teste->find("html");
}

?>
```

Pessoal, já tentei diversas formas já usei unset($teste) e não acontece nada, já tentei reescrever utilizando:

```
$teste = new simple_html_dom();
$teste->load_file("http://www.btolinux.com.br/");
```

OU

```
$teste = file_get_html("http://www.btolinux.com.br/");
```

E só piora...

Basicamente acredito ser um erro de persistência de objeto na memória, já que o erro que aparece no 3º objeto é:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in /var/www/html/crawler/simple_html_dom.php on line 1113

Bem, tentei de tudo, mas não encontro uma resposta...

para quem for tentar baixem a classe [simple_html_dom](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/latest/download)

Comment: Posta a classe que está sendo incluída ou um link para ela. Num primeiro momento eu arriscaria um palpite de que quem a criou usou uma propriedade estática onde não deveria.

Comment: Opa! Editei o texto apontando o link para a classe... tinha me esquecido de colocar.

Answer (score 2):

O pdonatilio resolveu o problema não usando a classe quando não houver o arquivo, mas isso resolve parte do problema. A questão central é que a classe gera um erro fatal e não será mais executada para criar novas instâncias, então os novos objetos estarão todos com erro. Não que a solução esteja errado, mas acho que isso deveria ser investigado.

Para mim é um bug da classe, porque uma classe deve escapar de erros simples como arquivo não encontrado. Nesse caso, você deveria procurar em [Lista de bugs do simple-dom-parser](http://sourceforge.net/p/simplehtmldom/bugs/) se não há relato do bug e relatar, caso não haja. O erro também pode estar na tentativa de escapar, problema de versão de php, etc., tem que conversar como o povo que desenvolveu, senão você dá uma curva neste problema específico, mas ele volta mais adiante por outra razão.

Comment: Opa camarada. Concordo 100% com o que você disse. Vou entrar em contato com o pessoal que desenvolveu a classe e procurar junto com eles uma solução melhor e mais elegante.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o Problema fazendo a seguinte alteração:

Substitui isso:

```
$teste = new simple_html_dom("http://www.btolinux.com.br/error/");
echo $teste->original_size."<br>";
if($teste->original_size !== 0){
   $teste->find("html");
}
```

Por isto

```
$html = @file_get_contents("http://www.btolinux.com.br/error/");
if ($html!='') {
   $teste = new simple_html_dom($html);
   echo 'SIZE: '.$teste->original_size."<br>";
   $teste->find("html")
}
```

E funcionou...
Bem Boa noite pessoal... e até uma próxima...